# Azure Devops: Call a Template from a inline script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-rm-template

I have a Template.yml having one parameter. I would like to call that template from a inline script. How can I achieve that?

Orchastrtor.yml

```
parameters:
  AzureSubscription: []

jobs:
- job: update
  condition: succeeded()
  pool: 
      vmImage: "windows-latest"
  steps:
  - task: AzurePowerShell@4
    displayName: Update
    inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'xxx'
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: |
            Write-Output "subscription is '${{ parameters.AzureSubscription }}' "
            $sub = ${{ parameters.AzureSubscription }}
            foreach($Result in $sub ){
                # Want to call my template from this.
               ../template/yaml -parameter 
            }
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
        FailOnStandardError: true
```

Template.Yaml - Having one parameter and 2 task.

```
parameters:
  azureSubscription: ''

steps:

  - task: AzurePowerShell@4
    displayName: Updating ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
      ScriptType: 'FilePath'
      ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Foundation/xx.ps1'
      azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

Can someone help me how can I call a template?

Comment: Calling a template from where? Are you using VSTS or Powershell console?

Comment: I have one Orchastrtor.yml which is having one inline script task. So inside script, i want to call a template.yml. I am using powershell

Comment: Is there any limitation that you can not add more than one task in your Orchastrtor.yml ? If not, then you can add the Trigger Pipeline task in Orchastrtor.yml to trigger template.yml pipeline.

Comment: Actually, there is some limitation which we want to achieve, so if I can call template from a script then our problem will be resolved. so looking for a solution

Comment: Can you show your template.yml?

Comment: Updated in the main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can't so easily pass dynamically azure subscription:

> @JoeGaggler this feature isn't supported today. Usage of service endpoints (Azure Subscription is one of kind) in release/build definition is controlled by some permissions. At the time of saving a release/build definition service validates that the author (whoever is saving the definition) has appropriate permissions on the endpoint. If we support variable replacements for service endpoint input then service can't validate that the author has required permissions or not and it might become a security issue.

You need to use workaround here. And by that I mean use pure powershell code including loging to Azure. So if your template would be

```yaml
parameters:
- name: 'group'
  type: string
- name: 'scriptPath'
  type: string

jobs:
- job:
  variables:
  - group: ${{ parameters.group }}
  steps:
  - pwsh: |
      $pscredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($(applicationId), $sp.SECRET)
      Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $(tenantId)
      ${{ parameters.scriptPath }}
    env:
      SECRET: secret
```

Here I assume that you will create one variable group per each subscription you have. Each grouo should have following values:

- applicationId
- secret (service principal secret considered also as secret on Azure Devops and this why env mapping is needed)
- tenant id

Then you will call it like:

```
parameters:
  groups: []

jobs:
- ${{ each subscriptionGroup parameters.groups}}:
  - template: ../template.yaml
      parameters:
        group: ${{ subscriptionGroup }}
        scriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Foundation/xx.ps1'
```

Drawback:

- previously you had multiple steps in one job, one you have one step in multiple jobs, thus it could take a bit longer to run

Comment: Indeed! this way is working bit longer than expected

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. But I think you can achieve the same results using an [expression with the `each` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword), that behaves like the loop your use case describes.

So your `Orchastrtor.yml` would be like this:

```
parameters:
  AzureSubscription: []

jobs:
- job: update
  pool: 
      vmImage: "windows-latest"
  steps:
  - ${{ each subscription in parameters.AzureSubscription }}:
    - template: ../template.yaml
      parameters:
        azureSubscription: ${{ subscription }}
```

Comment: Tried doing this. But issue is in my scenario, I dont have subscription List upfront. which I am retrieving from a task and passing as a parameter to call this yaml, And there it is failing as foreach always validate value during compile time. So I invoked from a script and it worked,